# Git merge with sub branches

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I have a master branch with a sub branch (branchA).  I have created another sub branch (branchB) from branchA.

If I wish to get the latest changes from branchA into branchB, is it as simple as sitting in branchB and doing?

```
git merge branchA
```

or do I need to do a:

```
git pull origin branchA
```

What's the difference here?  Doesn't pull do an implicit merge?  Does

```
git merge branchName
```

do an implicit pull on the branchName?  Getting confused...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it as simple as sitting in branchB and doing:
>
> ```
> git merge branchA
> ```

Yes, git has power in its simplicity.

> or do i need to do a:
>
> ```
> git pull origin branchA
> ```
>
> What's the difference here?

The only difference here refers to using a remote repository. If you're pushing code to a remote, like Github, from another machine (or working with another person) then you would want to fetch any updates from there. If all changes are just on your local machine, then a pull will provide no new information.

> Doesn't pull do an implicit merge?

Yes, it's shorthand for `git fetch` and then `git merge`

> Does
>
> ```
> git merge branchName
> ```
>
> do an implicit pull on the branchName?

Nope. Merge only uses your local branch. So, not to confuse you further, but your remotes have local "tracking branches" that you could merge like:

```
git merge remote/branchName
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the two branches are not already on your machine, you indeed need to retrieve them first:

```
git fetch -a
git checkout branchA
git pull
git checkout branchB
git pull
```

Once you have them on your machine, you can easily merge branchA into branchB using:

```
git checkout branchB
git merge branchA
```

Now branchB will contain the change from both branchA and branchB.

Comment: I already have local copies of both branches.  If, say, branchA is out of date locally (many devs working on it) and I sit in branchB and do a git merge branchA, will I get latest changes to branchA or will it merge my local copy of branchA into branchB?

Comment: You won't automatically get the latest remote changes when you do a merge, you need to pull the changes first. Basically you can skip `git fetch -a` in my example above, but the rest is needed.